# video is not playing in IE8 by mediaelement.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I am not able to play video in IE8 by using mediaelementjs.

I am using HTML5 video tag and I want the video to be played in IE8 and below browsers.

I know that IE8 doesn't support HTML5 video tag.Hence I am implementing mediaelement.js
to make the video play in IE8.

Can anyone tell me how to make the video play in IE8 using mediaelement.js(HTML5 video tag)?

Comment: Please post your codes :)

Comment: you can see the code by downloading the mediaelementjs from 
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/



By opening the demos folder and going to files like mediaelementplayer.html and mediaelement.html

opening them in IE8

Comment: Have you read this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099535/mediaelement-js-video-doesnt-play-in-ie8

or this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904736/flash-fallback-video-black-screen-no-video-only-audio-media-element

with the answer about the change of position into CSS? I tried but it doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: I tried changing the position yet it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2594152 - preference on StackOverflow is to show how YOU USE code, not where you got it from.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something's wrong with your `<script>` tag. IE takes HTML errors more seriously, if you forgot to close it / forgot `type="text/javascript"` and you chose for example `XHTML 1.0 STRICT` doctype, mediaelement.js can not be used. Or you can also have an error elsewhere of course, but we can't identify that for you unless showing us some code.

Comment: you can see the code by downloading the mediaelementjs from 
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/



By opening the demos folder and going to files like mediaelementplayer.html and mediaelement.html

opening them in IE8

Answer (score 0):

I also had this Issue. The position didnt do the Trick fist. 
I changed the according Javascript

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function(player, node) {
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
    }
});
```

to

```
jQuery('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function(player, node) {
        $('#' + node.id + '-mode').html('mode: ' + player.pluginType);
    }
});
```

Then change position: static;
and it works