# ActiveX control not accessible via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, windows-embedded

Please look at this simple sample code to embed the VLC web plugin in IE and access a property of the plugin:

```
    <div id="player">
        <object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
            id="vlc" 
            width="676px"
            height="386px" 
            classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">  
        </object>
    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="alert(vlc.VersionInfo);">
```

**This works fine on PC#1**, giving me the current Version of the plugin. On PC#2, on the other hand, this gives "undefined". From the debugger I can see that the vlc-object does not have the properties it should have.

What strikes me is that the plugin itself on PC#2 is capable of playing video streams (when adding the Src-Param to the object-tag). It just seems not capable of being accessed via JavaScript.

So far I've tried..

- changing IE security settings to super-low on PC#2
- adding the plugins classid to the Pre-Approved registry folder
- checked for Group Policies that might disable ActiveX in IE somehow
- several versions of VLC

**Any ideas on what could cause such a strange behavior are very welcome!**

**EDIT:** it might be relevant to add that PC#2 is running on Windows Embedded Standard (it's a WYSE ThinClient)..

Comment: Not enough information. What does "console.log(vlc)" print at PC#2?. IE versions? VLC versions? Other browsers behaviour?

Comment: Which IE version is on PC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem trying to access VLC object (both from NSAPI / ActiveX) from JS. On my case it depends from VLC release. Currently, if I use 2.0.2 all is ok (both NSAPI and AciveX). Newer releases seems to break JS wrapping of VLC object.

U can try with 2.0.2 release and check if u solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the dubious position to recommend Adobe Flash to someone. VLC active-X plugin may have more bugs than Flash since so many more people install Flash and use it inside Internet Explorer.
See Magnus Engdal's answer to this question [Video element is not displaying in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405265/video-element-is-not-displaying-in-ie8).

Another option would be to install a different browser: if you have the security clearance to install VLC surely you can also install Firefox or Google Chrome or Chromium or Opera...

Mardie questions are quite relevant. Are you otherwise restricted to IE? I am curious how this turns out.