# Video wont play on samsung smart tv

Tags: video, samsung-smart-tv

I have got a task to make web page with video in it. But, i face a problem with video wont play in **samsung smart tv eco j5500**.

I've already tried videojs but it wont play in IE v.8 i assume I.E has same specification with samsung smart tv browser.

I also tried install TIZEN but still figure it out how it work or how it build app and run in tv.

here's my code:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="95%" style="position:relative" autoplay>
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script>
var videoSource = new Array();
videoSource[0]='video/4.mp4';
videoSource[1]='video/2.mp4';
videoSource[2]='video/1.mp4';
videoSource[3]='video/3.mp4';
var videoCount = videoSource.length;

document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[0]);
function videoPlay(videoNum)
{
document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src",videoSource[videoNum]);
document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
i = 0;
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler() {
  i++;
  if(i >= videoCount) i =0;
  videoPlay(i);
}
</script>
```

what should i do guys? 
i really appreciate ur help

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405265/video-element-is-not-displaying-in-ie8

Comment: @shuabing I already check at your link, and i tried to play the video in IE 8 but still won work.Anywat do know what samsung tv use for browser?

Answer (score 0):

Tizen have APIs for different sorts of video playing. I would suggest you to use Tizen AVPlay API. Please Check this [Sample Guide](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenSampleGuide/tizen3461/index.html) and the [github link](https://github.com/SamsungDForum/PlayerAvplay) for sample app.

For details implementation You may take a look on [AVPlay API Reference Guide](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenApiGuide/tizen3001/index.html).